# Computing depth using Koszul complexes

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

### Context

$\newcommand{\iprod}{\mathbin{\llcorner}}$
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, let $J$ be an ideal of $A$ and let $M$ be an $A$-module.
By definition, the *depth* of $M$ relative to $J$, which I denote $\mathrm{depth}_A(J;M)$, is the smallest integer $n$ such that $\mathrm{Ext}^n_A(A/J, M) \neq 0$. By convention $\mathrm{depth}_A(J;M) = +\infty$ if no such $n$ exists.

Let $\underline{x} := (x_i)_{i \in I}$ be a (possibly infinite) family of generators of $J$. Consider $u : A^{(I)} \to A$ the linear map defined by $u(e_i) = x_i$, and let $\mathrm{K}_\bullet(\underline{x}, A)$ be the (homological) Koszul complex attached to $u$: its degree $n$ component is $\bigwedge^n A^{(I)}$, and the differential is the interior product $l \mapsto l  \iprod u$. More explicitly the differential sends $l_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge l_n$ to $$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1}u(l_i) \cdot l_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge l_{i-1} \wedge l_{i+1} \wedge \cdots \wedge l_n.
$$

Consider $\mathrm{K}^\bullet(\underline{x}, M)$ the cohomological Koszul complex attached to $u$ and $M$: it is the complex $\mathrm{Hom}\left(\mathrm{K}_\bullet(\underline{x}, A), M\right)$. Let $H^i(\underline{x}, M)$ be the $i$-th cohomology of this complex.

Bourbaki's *Algèbre commutative, Chapitre 10*, Theorem 1 of §1, n°3 states that $\mathrm{depth}_A(J;M)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that $H^n(\underline{x}, M) \neq 0$ (and again by convention, if there is no such $n$, then the depth is $+\infty$).

### Question

The above theorem surprises me: normally to compute $\mathrm{depth}_A(J;M)$, one would need to pick a free resolution $C_\bullet \to A/J$, look at $\mathrm{Hom}(C_\bullet, M)$ and see where the cohomology is non-zero, yet the theorem says that we can get the result by following this same procedure but replacing $C_\bullet$ by $\mathrm{K}_\bullet(\underline{x}, A)$, which is a complex of free module satisfying $H_0(\mathrm{K}_\bullet(\underline{x}, A)) = A/J$ but which is not necessarily exact, hence not a free resolution in the usual sense.

I can follow the proof of this theorem given in Bourbaki, but it feels very unmotivated. I *feel* like there is a spectral sequence argument hidden under the rug but I'm not quite sure.
I am asking if there is such argument which can prove the theorem and understand it better, I'm also asking for any insight on what is really going on in this theorem, and to get why in this case we can get informations on $\mathrm{Ext}^i_A(A/J, M)$ using something that is not a resolution of $A/J$.

Note that I am aware of the fact that in the case $A$ is local and noetherian, everything is tied to length of regular $M$-sequences in $J$, but I'd like remain as much as possible in the general situation of arbitrary ring, ideal and module.

Comment: This is a bit different to what you're after, but it might help to look at local cohomology, since it admits a description as something genuinely geometric (Cech cohomology of the complement) and as a limit of Kozsul complexes. I recall trying to interpret the Kozsul complex along these lines as a Cech approximation, but I never got it all straightened out, maybe you'd have more luck.

Comment: @ChrisH Thank you for the suggestion! I've been meaning to dive into local cohomology a bit more seriously for a while now, so I guess this adds another reason to the list.